# How do I flag a comment on a Documentation Topic Request?

Tags: support, documentation

Say I find comments on a Topic Request that are spam, rude, or otherwise not constructive. How do I flag this content for moderator attention?

Comment: Say you find a Topic Request that is spam.. How do you flag that?

Comment: @Vogel612 There's a "Dismiss" button. Just select "is not a real request"

Comment: @4castle that doesn't carry any of the implications that come with spam flags and is accordingly an unsatisfactory workaround